# HABTM not working with polymorphic association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a polymorphic association: my user model can be of type 'student' or of type 'employer'.  I am trying to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many association between the student model and another model called the 'project' model.  When I try to call:

controller:

```
@my_projects = current_user.projects
```

view:

```
<% @my_projects.where(state: :posting).each do |project| %>
    <%= project.students %><br>
<% end %>
```

I am told:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "projects_users" does not exist
```

I have defined a table called "projects_students" though, which i think should work.  I don't want to have a "project_users" table because the table is only for students, not for employers.  How do I fix this?  Here are my models:

```
class Student < User
    has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

-

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are building `@my_projects` from a starting context of a `User` object.  If you run `User.first.projects` and `Student.first.projects` from the Rails console, you will see that one tries to use `projects_users` as the join table and the other tries to use `projects_students`.  So rather than force a special "join_table" name in the model as I had suggested originally you could do something like this when you look up the projects:

```
@my_projects = current_user.becomes(Student).projects
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.  But is this a bad practice?  Shouldn't it automatically know the join table?  Also, for some reason when the join table is created the student_id is not being passed into it.

Comment: OK, now I see the real issue.  I've updated my answer to offer another suggestion that avoids explicitly defining a join_table name in the model.